# What is List Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, workflow

I am SharePoint new beginner. I want to know what is the list workflow and list workflow effect.

I try to google and find the answer but no exactly answer.

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint workflow can be categorized to site workflow, list workflow and reusable workflow. List Workflow is workflow which is Associated with one particular List. It waits for events happened on that specific list and start actions pre-configured.

A simple introduction blog:http://devendra-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/02/list-workflow-vs-reusable-wokflow-vs.html

Some docs which may be help:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo

Comment: Hi Jerry, thank you answer and information support. May i know that what situation need to use List workflow? any example??thanks!!!!

Comment: @ericso , when you want to create a workflow only needs to handle a certain list, then a list workflow will be the most straightforward choice. If you want to associate the workflow to a certain content type. In other words you want to use it in different lists/libraries, a reusable workflow may be a better choice.

Comment: @ericso, an example here:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/sharepoint-designer-2013-create-a-list-workflow-in-sharepoi/

Comment: Hi Jerry, thank you support. i think i understand more about what is list workflow . thanks

Comment: @ericso glad to be help. You can accept the reply as answer if it solves you question